# Run Selenium IDE test case on web request

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide, webrequest

I would like to run a Selenium IDE test case when a web request is sent to my computer via an API. How would I go about doing this, or is this impossible using the IDE?

OS: Windows 10
Running Firefox 54 with legacy Selenium IDE

Comment: way too broad. the API will do the heavy lifting and trigger the test case, but to actually say "how to go about doing this" is impossible with so little details

Answer (score 1):

Since Selenium IDE works with the Firefox Browser you would need a web page on your local machine to receive the request and then display some sort of trigger that IDE can look for while it is polling that page. One example might be:

You have a web page hosted on your local machine (using something like mysql and php) that contains a dynamic link that updates when the API is triggered.

Your Selenium script could read that page every X seconds and check if the trigger is present.

Using the Sideflow (flow control) plugin your script might look like:

```
storeText | (xpath-to-trigger-text) | trigger
while     | '${trigger}' != true
pause     | 60000
refreshAndWait
storeText | (xpath-to-trigger-text) | trigger
endWhile
(do something useful here)
```

There are other ways to frame this but without more detail it is hard to give a more specific solution.